# react-native-file-access:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I get this error. when trying to run react-native run-android and the same with yarn android

> 

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-file-access:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s

Tried googling the error and tried the solutions and it seems to be related to the react native module

Comment: What's your react native version ? 
For React Native 0.64 and older, use 1.x.x. For React Native 0.65+, use 2.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the Kotlin version in the build.gradle at the project level

```
`buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.0" 
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }`
```